# guarantee events order in debezium

Tags: debezium

in debezium's doc, change event key's structure is like

```
{
 "schema": { 
    "type": "struct",
 "name": "mysql-server-1.inventory.customers.Key", 
 "optional": false, 
 "fields": [ 
      {
        "field": "id",
        "type": "int32",
        "optional": false
      }
    ]
  },
 "payload": { 
    "id": 1001
  }
}
```

1. question1: events for the row in table `customers` which `id=1001` always have the same key, right？
2. question2: since kafka will send the data with the same key to the same partition, so I can say the events for `customers.id=1001` can be consumed orderly, right?
3. question3: if I alter the primary key to varchar, the key will change so the partition number maybe change, in this case how can I guarantee the events always consumed orderly?

Answer (score 0):

1: Yes.

2: Yes.

3: If you change the primary key -- either just its value, or even its type -- you won't have any ordering guarantees between events before and after that change.